# ¿Cómo agregar una lista de objetos como propiedad en una clase?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quisiera saber como puedo agregar una propiedad de tipo lista en una clase, esa lista puede ser de diferentes clases, no sólo de una, esa lista me servirá para hacer un binding a un grid. He intentado esto pero no funciona.

```
public partial class help : secondaryForm.secondaryForm
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<T> objectList { get; set; }

    public help()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gridControlHelp.DataSource = objectList;
    }

    private void help_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            setFormTitle(title);
            setFormDescription(description);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"help_Load: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Como mencioné anteriormente esa lista puede ser de alguna clase y me servirá para mostrar los datos en un grid, estaré agradecido a la persona que me ayude.

Comment: Cuando coloques codigo, colocalo como texto para que sea facil copiar y pegar y resolver el error.

Comment: Entendido tomaré nota para la próxima.

Answer (score 1):

Para que puedas usar T, tu clase debe ser de tipo T

```
public class MiClase<T>
{
  public string title { get; set; }
  public string description { get; set; }
  public List<T> objectList { get; set; }
}
```

Despues llamas e instancias del tipo que tu quieras y tu Listado sera de tipo string por ejemplo, te falta el metodo donde llenas tu listado.

```
public partial class help : secondaryForm.secondaryForm
{  
    MiClase<string> miClase = new MiClase<string>();

    public help()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gridControlHelp.DataSource = miClase.objectList;
    }

    private void help_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            setFormTitle(title);
            setFormDescription(description);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"help_Load: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero mi clase en sí es un Form, cuando le agrego que sea de tipo T da errores en el  InitializeComponent() y los controles que tengo me los deja inaccesible.

Comment: No tienes que usar tu clase de tipo form para hacer un modelo.

Comment: Como sería entonces, la verdad no se mucho sobre generics.

Comment: Tal cual deje mi ejemplo, tu modelo seria generio y en tu form lo llamas. Te actualizo la respuesta, pero copia el codigo y quita la foto

Comment: Ya agregué el código